# Best way to sort page disposition on client side

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I'm working on a MVC project in which I display a ViewModel in several partial views within a table. I have a control in which the user can change how the table is displayed, like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
    partial view 1  partial view 2
  </td> 
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
    partial view 3  partial view 4
  </td> 
 </tr>
</table>
```

or

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>
   partial view 1
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   partial view 2
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   partial view 3
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   partial view 4
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Any time a user wants to change how the view is displayed, he has to click the submit button of the from, and the application has to make the request to the server, get the results, and according to a flag (TableDisposition = 1 or 2), load some divs.

I know this is not the best way to do it, but my lack of knowledge regarding  client side coding (javascript/jquery) is making it impossible for me to do this in a more efficient way.

Any input will be much appreciated.

EDIT: Solved in the comments.

Comment: will the result change when the user clicks the submit button? or it returns the same result?

Comment: If the user makes a new request with the submit button, results will change. That is expected because it's a search/details view

Comment: You just put a new button to change the view.. fill both div with values when clicking submit and show only one div. When user clicks button to change view hide the current div and show the other div..

Comment: I'll try that, thank you.

Comment: Something like this? http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/ViewModeSwitch/

Comment: @MoshFeu THANKS A LOT! I downloaded and studied the source, and thanks to that I was able to do my first jquery function, which the desired result.

Comment: My pleasure.. Good luck!

Comment: @Rambo3, maybe you should answer your question with the solution, just for the future readers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I started loading the viewModel in two tables, each one in a div with absolute positioning. Then I made a function to hide one of those tables:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#divTable1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
});
```

Finally, I made a function which is triggered by pressing a button:

```
 $("#btnAlternateView").click(function () {
    if ($("#divTable2").css('visibility') == 'hidden') {
        $("#divTable2").css('visibility','visible');
        $("#divTable1").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    }
    else {
        $("#divTable2").css('visibility','hidden');
        $("#divTable1").css('visibility', 'visible');
    }
});
```

And that was it. Works like a charm.